# Php-Json parse with in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, json

I use laravel Json_Encode. I want parse PHP Json in Java Script.

I use this code on PHP

```
    public function searchAutoCompleteAjax(){
    $keyword = Input::get('keyword');

    $result = array();
    if(!empty(trim($keyword))){
        $mongoResult = MongoDB::instance(true)->collection("items")->like('name',$keyword)->limit(0,5)->fetch();

        if($mongoResult){
            foreach ($mongoResult as $key => $item) {
                $result[] = $item['name'];
            }
        }
    }


    echo json_encode(array("error"=>0,"message"=>"Success","result"=>$result));
}
```

And this is my JavaScript code

```js
$(function(){

 var currencies = [
    { value: 'I want Parse Value - 1' },
    { value: 'I want Parse Value - 2' },
    { value: 'I want Parse Value - 3' },
    { value: 'I want Parse Value - 4' },
    { value: 'I want Parse Value - 5' },
  ];

  // setup autocomplete function pulling from currencies[] array
  $('#search-box').autocomplete({
    lookup: currencies,
 });
});
```

You have any solutions?
Thank you

Comment: could you give an example of the json you want to parse and of the result you want to achieve?

Comment: @acontell ` $mongoResult = MongoDB::instance(true)->collection("items")->like('name',$keyword)->limit(0,5)->fetch() `

i want parse name in java script